# Power Apps Sort and SortByColumns won't work

Tags: sorting, powerapps

New to Powerapps, managed to get thus far until trying to sort collections....

I have collection call Var_AcctList with columns called Role and SiteName and have been trying to sort it, or collection derived from filtering it, etc.  It keeps telling me that it Cannot sort on  the expression type. Can anyone help telling me what is wrong with this code?

var_AcctList comes from a flow with powerbi query of a SQL db.

```
ClearCollect(
    var_AcctList,    
    ForAll(
        Table(ParseJSON(SourceList.Run().acctarry)),
        {
            SiteName: Value.'Accts[SiteName]',
            Role: Value.'Accts[RoleName]',
            LoginName: Value.Accts[LoginName]',
            FirstName: Value.'Accts[FirstName]',
            LastName: Value.'Accts[LastName]',
            Email: Value.'Accts[EmailAddress1]'
        }
    )
);

ClearCollect(
    sortAcctsList,    
    SortByColumns(
        AddColumns(
            Filter(
                var_AcctList,
                Role="buyer"
            ),
            "sortSiteName",SiteName
        ),
        "sortSiteName"
    )
);
```

I have even tried the simpliest form like below without luck.

```
SortByColumns(var_AcctList,"SiteName")
```

I had tried putting these codes in OnStart of the App or on a label in a screen.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? What do you get with: `SortByColumns(  Filter( var_AcctList, Role="buyer" ), "SiteName" );`

Comment: What is the type of the `SiteName` column?

Comment: @carlosfigueira I edited my OP to include the code that create var_AcctList.  I tried changing Value.'Accts[SiteName]' to Text.'Accts[SiteName]', it throw an error in App checker.  Sam, that code is marked with error.  The function 'SortByColumns'  has some invalid arguments.  And another error Cannot sort on the expression type.

Comment: Thanks to carlos' question, I searched about type in PowerApps and learned some more.  I changed the parseJSON schema to Text(Value.'Accts[SiteName]',) for all the fields, now sortng works.  Love you guys!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the parseJSON schema to Text(Value.'Accts[SiteName]') for all the fields.  The SortByColumns function no longer throw App Checker error.  Thanks to the hint of Carlos.